# Get list of slugs for a specific product attribute on archive pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I need to display some custom icons on the product overview (category, archive) page based on a set of ingredients (which is a Woo product attribute).

I am hooking in at `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title` and that is the right place to display what I want. However, I can't get a list of the slugs for the attributes easily. My goal is to get an array of slugs that is like `['onion', 'fresh-lettuce', 'cheese']` or whatever.

My current try is something like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', function () {
    global $product;
    $attrs = $product->get_attributes();
    $slugs = $attrs->get_slugs( 'ingredients' );
    var_dump( $slugs );
});
```

But that does not work.

Note that `$product->get_attributes()` works, but is the same for every product on the category page.

Please advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following using [`WC_Product` `get_attribute()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_attributes) method:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'loop_display_ingredients', 15 );
function loop_display_ingredients() {
    global $product;
    // The attribute slug
    $attribute = 'ingredients';
    // Get attribute term names in a coma separated string
    $term_names = $product->get_attribute( $attribute );

    // Display a coma separted string of term names
    echo '<p>' . $term_names . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Now if you want to **get the term slugs** in a coma separated list, you will use the following:

```
// The attribute slug
$attribute = 'ingredients';
// Get attribute term names in a coma separated string
$term_names = $product->get_attribute( $attribute );

// Get the array of the WP_Term objects
$term_slugs = array();
$term_names = str_replace(', ', ',', $term_names);
$term_names_array = explode(',', $term_names);
if(reset($term_names_array)){
    foreach( $term_names_array as $term_name ){
        // Get the WP_Term object for each term name
        $term = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, 'pa_'.$attribute );
        // Set the term slug in an array
        $term_slugs[] = $term->slug;
    }
    // Display a coma separted string of term slugs
    echo '<p>' . implode(', ', $term_slugs); . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The code snippet works great. I am surprised Woo doesn't have a function built-in to do this... seems like the built-in get_attribute method on the products is already getting all the terms and gluing them together manually. In any case your code is spot-on. Thanks.